# Why isnt hinttext of textfield veritcally aligned?

Tags: flutter

In this example I show you that in a Row with text and a textfield the text is not aligned with the hinttext of the textfield:

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Container(
        color: Colors.redAccent,
        child: Text(
          'check if textfield is aligned',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
        )),
    const SizedBox(width: 8),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
        child: TextField(
          enableSuggestions: false,
          autocorrect: false,
          textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'test',
            hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
            isDense: true,
            isCollapsed: true,
            border: InputBorder.none,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

[image]

and also doesnt work if i remove collapse and dense:

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Container(
        color: Colors.redAccent,
        child: Text(
          'check if textfield is aligned',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
        )),
    const SizedBox(width: 8),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
        child: TextField(
          enableSuggestions: false,
          autocorrect: false,
          textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'test',
            hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
            border: InputBorder.none,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

[image]

However, if i had height 2 to the style of the hinttext it works:

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Container(
        color: Colors.redAccent,
        child: Text(
          'check if textfield is aligned',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
        )),
    const SizedBox(width: 8),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
        child: TextField(
          enableSuggestions: false,
          autocorrect: false,
          textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'test',
            hintStyle: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .bodyMedium
                ?.copyWith(height: 2),
            border: InputBorder.none,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

[image]

If you notice the hinttext is always slightly below center. Only when I had change the style height to 2 or more does it center. with height null and 1 it doesnt work.